# How many independent parameters does the fourth-order tensor have under rotation?

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove mathematically that isotropic materials have only two independent parameters.
From [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63937/symmetrizedarray-of-stiffness-compliance-tensor/120099#120099), you can get the following description.

---

*Index symmetries:*

A stiffness tensor $C$ is a fourth-order tensor with components $c_{ijkl}$ which maps symmetric second-order tensors into symmetric second-order tensors, i.e., $\sigma_{ij} = c_{ijkl} \varepsilon_{kl}$ (linear elastic law), $\sigma$ (stress) and $\varepsilon$ (strain) being arbitrary symmetric second-order tensors. Due to the symmetry of the second-order tensors, $C$ is allowed to be minor symmetric, i.e., $c_{ijkl} = c_{jikl} = c_{ijlk}$. The not minor symmetric part of $C$ is irrelevant for the elastic law and is dropped. If the stress $\sigma$ is to be related to an elastic energy potential $W$ (referred to as hyperelastic behavior), i.e., $\sigma = \partial W / \partial \varepsilon$, then, due to Schwarz's theorem, the stiffness tensor $c_{ijkl} = \partial^2 W / \partial \varepsilon_{ij} \partial \varepsilon_{kl}$ has to possess the major symmetry, i.e., $c_{ijkl} = c_{klij}$.

*Material symmetry:*

A material with stiffness $C$ is said to possess the material symmetry group $G$ (e.g., triclinic, orthotropic, transversally isotropic, ...) if

\begin{equation}
C = Q \star C  \qquad Q \in G
\end{equation}

holds, where $Q$ are second-order tensors, referred to as symmetry transformations of $C$. The product $\hat{C} = Q \star C$ (referred to here as Rayleigh product) is defined in components as

\begin{equation}
\hat{c}_{ijkl}
= Q_{im}Q_{jn}Q_{ko}Q_{lp}c_{mnop}
\end{equation}

For solids, $G$ is a subset of the orthogonal group. In solid mechanics, if suffices to consider rotation matrices $Q$ from the rotational group $SO(3)$. If $G = \{I\}$, $I$ being the identity matrix, then $C$ is said to triclinic. If $G$ possesses more than the identity transformation, then different material classes can be defined (different anisotropy types). If $G = SO(3)$, the $C$ is said to be isotropic (no direction dependency).

---

**I want to use mathematical method to get the number of independent parameters needed for the fourth-order tensor to make $C = Q \star C  (Q \in  SO(3))$ under the rotation of group SO(3). What should I do?**